# Taking server path into account in angular route

Tags: angularjs

I am enhancing an ASP.NET MVC application with angularJS for selected pages. The primary means of navigating the site is still full page request, but some pages contain angular views and associated controllers for interactivity.

Currently, I achieve this by having something like this in the server side view:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl" ng-include="exampleview.html"></div>
```

However, I would prefer to not inline controller and template definition like that and handle this through routing instead. However, angular routing only uses the client side of the URL (i.e. the parts after the first `#`). For various reasons, the page URL should remain `http://domain.com/Example/Action` instead of `http://domain.com/Example/Action/#/example` (this is just ugly) or `http://domain.com/#/example` (this will not work because I actually need the server side view as well).

Is there a way to make angular routing take the whole URL path into account instead of just the client part (and works in IE9)?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: @jb-nizet I probably should have mentioned that this needs to work in IE9 and up.